Forlorn high schooler falls in love in 1970's bayou
I saw this short color film (15 mins.) several times in Jr. High (1974-1977) and High School (1977-1980). It follows a teenage boy who looked, to my recollection, like a young Kyle McLachlan. His mom sends him to a local store to pick up a few things. He travels by boat with his dog in a bayou looking swamp/river. I think it was a canoe or rowboat.  Upon his arrival, the store owners teenage niece(?) is working the register. The boy is immediately smitten.  So much so, he forgets to make his purchases. 
He goes home and orders a suit from a Sears type catalog.  After awaiting the mailman's delivery for weeks the suit finally arrives. It is ill fitting and I think he even cuts the skinnier part of the necktie since he can't even tie it properly. He heads back in his boat with his dog to nervously approach the girl of his dreams. When he gets there she is not in the store, he begins to leave disappointed and then hears her laughing from the parking lot out front. He perks up, but it all comes crashing down when he finds she is flirting with an older jock boy with a muscle car. Crushed, he leaves, walking back to his dog and boat and all the way off the dock into the water.  He then climbs back in the boat soaking wet and leaves. The end.
I was never quite sure what we were to take from this or if there was even some hidden moral at all, that escaped my teenage mind. All I do know is that I loved this film and it stuck with me for years.  Any time it was shown, which was always in health class, I was always excited to see it again and again.  It pops back in my brain from time to time but all searches for it, or at least it's title have proved futile. It was or at least appeared to be a recent film at the time. So I would assume it was made in the very early 70's.  
I grew up and still live in Washington State and this seemed to take place down South so fashion sense was different from up here but it was really good quality film-wise. So it was not old, grainy, faded nor was it educational or preachy.  I suppose if I could compare the vibe of the film it would be similar to Cipher in the Snow, but not depressing or heavy-handed.
